# Real Time AC Current Sensing

Tags: microcontroller, ac, current-measurement, current-sensing, current-sensor

I'm trying to analyse the harmonics present in different household devices's current waveforms. For this, I need a CT based current sensor which can sample data quite accurately and quickly (around 5% error, atleast 50 times an AC cycle).
I have searched in the internet and found the below few :

https://www.amazon.in/Single-Phase-Current-Sensor-Module-Arduino/dp/B01M1KD163?tag=googinhydr18418-21

https://www.amazon.in/xcluma-Sct-013-030-Non-Invasive-Current-Sensor/dp/B072QL2D3F?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=3d26d24b-f11d-47ad-aa42-7236f8648b08

These seem to do the job of calculating the rms current and provide the data which can be fed to a data converter. But none of them satisfies my need in obtaining a real-time continuous data of the current drawn by the load.
It would be helpful if anyone could point me a better current sensor/system module which can be interfaced with a micro-controller to process the signals.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for product recommendations will cause your question to be closed.

> For this, I need a CT based current sensor which can sample data quite accurately and quickly (around 5% error, at least 50 times an AC cycle).

CT current sensors are "current transformers". They transform the primary current into another current to be fed to the monitoring circuit. They do not sample the current.

> These seem to do the job of calculating the rms current ...

No, they do not calculate RMS current. They don't calculate anything but attempt to drive the transformed current through the secondary load or burden resistor.

> ... and provide the data which can be fed to a data converter.

They provide an analog signal.

> But none of them satisfies my need in obtaining a real-time continuous data of the current drawn by the load.

Both of them give a continuous analog signal.

> It would be helpful if anyone could point me a better current sensor/system module which can be interfaced with a micro-controller to process the signals.

Have a look at http://openenergymonitor.org where much of this work is already solved for you.

---

Note that there are no datasheets available for either device you linked to. This means they are a bad choice. Amazon is not a recommended electronics component supplier.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't buy the devices you link, as there is no datasheet. One seems to be a transformer, the other seems to be Hall effect based, but there is no information available, notably on bandwidth which seems to be of interest to you.

If you want 50 samples per 50Hz period, that's 2500 samples per second, so you need at least several kHz bandwidth, more if you want good signal shape to measure harmonics and glitches with higher sample rate.

Check the Current Sensors category at Mouser:

https://www.mouser.fr/Sensors/Current-Sensors/_/N-7gqeu/

You can search by frequency range, for example this [transformer](https://www.mouser.fr/ds/2/192/CT08-1003175.pdf) covers 47Hz-6kHz.

Also at Farnell:

http://uk.farnell.com/lem/la-55-p/current-transducer-50a-pcb/dp/1617405

This one is hall-based and specced up to 100kHz. This manufacturer offers plenty of products for this purpose, you should find one fitting your requirements.

An easy DIY way to do this would be to feed the output from the LEM sensor into the audio input of a laptop, plenty of programs will allow you to FFT the waveform, extract harmonics, etc.